# Parsing text with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, coffeescript

apologies for the repeat, but I messed up my question last time

I have some data that looks something like this

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

where each object looks something like `{count: 90, bla: blah, label: "USA", bla2: blah2}`

I want to convert each object into the form

```
{text: "USA", weight: 90}
```

so total I will have

```
[{text: "USA", weight: 90},{text: "France", weight: 80}... etc..]
```

(so change label to text, change count to weight, put them in that order, and ignore any other fields other than count or label)

I need to do this with coffeescript

Comment: This has very little to do with JSON, also JS objects are unsorted structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick comprehension should do:

```
arr = [Object, Object, Object...]
result = ({text: o.label, weight: o.count} for o in arr)
```

Comment: sweet, thanks! i didn't realize i could do comprehensions in coffeescript like in python but that makes everything quite easy